# Mysql Left Join and Join in same query - syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Using MySQL.  Two joins as below work fine:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM t1 
  JOIN db2.t2 AS  t2  
  JOIN t3 ON t1.id=t3.id  
 WHERE 1;
```

However, following gives syntax error:

```
    SELECT *
      FROM t1 
 LEFT JOIN db2.t2 AS  t2  
      JOIN t3 ON t1.id=t3.id  
     WHERE 1;
```

I wish to use LEFT JOIN and JOIN in same query (many other question/answers on `LEFT JOIN` on SO haven't helped in this issue so far)

Comment: Put in question here what you got error?

Comment: How are you joining `t1`and `t2`? There's no `ON` clause. Anyway, try to invert the joining order (first with `t3` and then with `t2`

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE authors.url='abcd' AND hide_status='none' ORDER BY id DESC ' at line 5
(I changed the field names in original question).
Also, the reason I figure its not a syntax issue elsewhere is --- removing the word "LEFT" from the query works. Putting "LEFT JOIN" instead of "JOIN" in first join breaks the query.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the query here a bit to abstract the gist of the issue --- I will put the original one here (but can't find option to edit my question :-/)

Comment: Where is `WHERE authors.url='abcd' AND hide_status='none'`?

Comment: @Oscar Perez: Indeed the issue was what you mentioned. Even in my original query - I had no ON clause in the LEFT JOIN. Bit surprisingly, simple JOIN does not seem to have mandatory ON clause requirement (perhaps does on matching field names by default?), but LEFT JOIN has.  If you can add your comment as answer, it is the right one to accept.

Comment: @Sadikhasan: Sorry for the confusing wording of the question and thanks for the help. As you will find from comments above, Oscar's comment solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you lack an `ON` clause in the first `JOIN`.

As stated on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html , `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `OUTER` joins need to have an `ON` clause.

It should be something like:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN db2.t2 AS  t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
     JOIN t3 ON t1.id=t3.id  
    WHERE 1;
```

(Of course, adjust the condition to your needs)

Comment: Thanks for the crisp solution and doc reference as well.